# Evaluation metric for the hole validation set lower than the minimum metric if we broke the validation dataset into parts

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, computer-vision

I have trained a neural network to semantically segment cars and road, after the training the IOU for road was lower than expected 0.6 . My validation dataset is made of 6020 samples batched into batches of 2 that gives 3010 batches for the validation set. So i decided to evaluate 100 batches at a time to see at what batches septically my model was not doing well, to my surprise the minimum score that i got when i evaluated my validation set in parts of 100 was 0.65 that is bigger than the average that i got for the hole validation set which is 0.6. It is also interesting that the car class seems unaffected and the number makes sense. Below the metrics for the hole validation set, and also broken into parts of 100.

```
Hole validation set 
3010/3010 [==============================] - 183s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.5724 - road: 0.6014 - car: 0.5051 - nothing: 0.6105
Parts of 100
100/100 [==============================] - 7s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7375 - road: 0.7732 - car: 0.4873 - nothing: 0.9520
100/100 [==============================] - 8s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7592 - road: 0.8453 - car: 0.4837 - nothing: 0.9485
100/100 [==============================] - 11s 67ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.8098 - road: 0.9285 - car: 0.5226 - nothing: 0.9784
100/100 [==============================] - 12s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.8263 - road: 0.9372 - car: 0.5660 - nothing: 0.9757
100/100 [==============================] - 14s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.8244 - road: 0.9118 - car: 0.5875 - nothing: 0.9740
100/100 [==============================] - 15s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7795 - road: 0.8875 - car: 0.5126 - nothing: 0.9384
100/100 [==============================] - 17s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7834 - road: 0.8736 - car: 0.5153 - nothing: 0.9612
100/100 [==============================] - 19s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.8130 - road: 0.8931 - car: 0.5714 - nothing: 0.9743
100/100 [==============================] - 21s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.6946 - road: 0.7718 - car: 0.4164 - nothing: 0.8954
100/100 [==============================] - 23s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7878 - road: 0.8837 - car: 0.5338 - nothing: 0.9460
100/100 [==============================] - 24s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7909 - road: 0.8890 - car: 0.5311 - nothing: 0.9527
100/100 [==============================] - 26s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7897 - road: 0.9035 - car: 0.5182 - nothing: 0.9475
100/100 [==============================] - 28s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7445 - road: 0.8074 - car: 0.5080 - nothing: 0.9180
100/100 [==============================] - 29s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.6936 - road: 0.7222 - car: 0.4781 - nothing: 0.8807
100/100 [==============================] - 32s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7042 - road: 0.7867 - car: 0.4446 - nothing: 0.8813
100/100 [==============================] - 33s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.6323 - road: 0.6535 - car: 0.4699 - nothing: 0.7734
100/100 [==============================] - 35s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7333 - road: 0.8465 - car: 0.3986 - nothing: 0.9548
100/100 [==============================] - 37s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7687 - road: 0.7995 - car: 0.5799 - nothing: 0.9265
100/100 [==============================] - 38s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7581 - road: 0.8168 - car: 0.5377 - nothing: 0.9198
100/100 [==============================] - 40s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7928 - road: 0.8698 - car: 0.5370 - nothing: 0.9716
100/100 [==============================] - 43s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7515 - road: 0.7526 - car: 0.5849 - nothing: 0.9171
100/100 [==============================] - 44s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.8145 - road: 0.8977 - car: 0.5811 - nothing: 0.9647
100/100 [==============================] - 46s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7546 - road: 0.7927 - car: 0.5255 - nothing: 0.9454
100/100 [==============================] - 47s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.6810 - road: 0.7231 - car: 0.3915 - nothing: 0.9285
100/100 [==============================] - 51s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7310 - road: 0.8266 - car: 0.3966 - nothing: 0.9699
100/100 [==============================] - 50s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7414 - road: 0.8506 - car: 0.4233 - nothing: 0.9504
100/100 [==============================] - 54s 62ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7688 - road: 0.8624 - car: 0.4775 - nothing: 0.9665
100/100 [==============================] - 55s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7102 - road: 0.7068 - car: 0.4613 - nothing: 0.9626
100/100 [==============================] - 56s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.6963 - road: 0.6890 - car: 0.4415 - nothing: 0.9584
100/100 [==============================] - 58s 61ms/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7986 - road: 0.8196 - car: 0.6061 - nothing: 0.9701
10/10 [==============================] - 74s 2s/step - loss: 0.0000e+00 - Mean_IOU: 0.7718 - road: 0.8463 - car: 0.5371 - nothing: 0.9318
```

The third class 'nothing' is when a pixel doesn't belong to neither car or road, the loss is 0 because i didn't use it when evaluating the model right now, but it is calculated during training. I also observed a strange behaviour during training that i believe it is linked to this. At the beginning of each epoch the metric for the road is around 0.9 and then starts to drop as the model continues training, when it reaches the end of the epoch it is around 0.5. When the next epoch starts it is 0.9 again and the circle repeats. The model that i train is not a standard segmentation model but a birds eye view segmentation model using the nuscenes dataset by motional.

....................